# Как работает токен в JWT?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, postman

В работе веб-приложения должна быть настроена секьюрити, при логировании мы должны получить токен как я понимаю в ответе, потом он должен каждый раз отпраляться при каждом запросе, требующем авторизации? Обьясните пожалуйста кто знает

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jwt+spring&oq=jwt+spring&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.3272j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: а вот интересно как лучше отделить запросы, к которым нужна авторизация от других?